# How to send byte data over gRPC with C/C++?

Tags: c++, grpc

So I'm using gRPC to store data in a key-value store.

The protos look like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package keyvaluestore;

service KeyValueStore {
  rpc AddUser(Credentials) returns (Response) {}
  rpc Get(Request) returns (Response) {}
  rpc Put(Request) returns (Response) {}
  rpc Cput(Request) returns (Response) {}
  rpc Delete(Request) returns (Response) {}
}

message Credentials {
  string user = 1;
  string passwd = 2;
}

message Request {
  string user = 1;
  string key = 2;
  bytes val = 3;
  bytes val2 = 4;
  string addr = 5;
  string command = 6;
}

message Response {
  bytes val = 1;
  uint32 nbytes = 2;
  string message = 3;
}
```

Right now, the issue is that if we send over say, an image as byte data which can include the null byte, then when the server receives it in the `Request` object, it treats it as a string; when it does this it only reads it up the the first null byte.

How we pack the `Request` object on the client side:

```
bool KeyValueStoreClient::Put(const string& user, const string& key, const char* val) {
  Request req;
  req.set_user(user);
  req.set_key(key);
  req.set_val(val);

  ClientContext ctx;
  Response res;
  Status status = stub_->Put(&ctx, req, &res);
}
```

Server receives `req->val()` as a string instead of `char*`:

```
Status KeyValueStoreServiceImpl::Put(ServerContext* ctx, const Request* req, Response* res) {
  // req->val() is a string

}
```

Comment: `it treats it as a string; when it does this it only reads it up the the first null byte` This is not how `std::string` works; it can contain null bytes in the middle just fine.

Answer (score 3):

In your method `Put` the `val` argument is a `const char*`, not a `std::string`.

Protobuf [documentation for C++ generated code (i.e., the interface to your messages)](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated?hl=zh-CN#proto3_string) says that when *setting* a value using a `const char*` (the `void set_foo(const char* value)` overload) it uses the first `\0` as a terminator.

Tell it the size explicitly by using the `void set_foo(const char* value, int size)` overload.

Comment: Your answer unpacks a lot of info quickly, nice! From the docs on that overloaded function above: "string size is given explicitly rather than determined by looking for a null-terminator byte".